# Closed shapes with Newton 2

Tags: after-effects

I'm trying to simulate water filling up a closed sphere, but I'm having trouble getting Newton to recognize that my box is empty on the inside but has borders. It only sees my box as a solid object and I am unable to put anything else inside of it.

I've tried removing the fill and playing around with the box's properties but it doesn't seem to be affecting anything. I know it's possible because I've seen a few videos using the technique, but not a single one explaining how to do it.

In short, I want to be able to create a "hollow" box that Newton can see and that I can fill with a bunch of tiny balls.

Comment: Hi - I think you need to post some screenshots of what you're trying to do.  Newton is a 2D physics engine, so I'm not sure how you'd use it to fill a sphere?  Are you filling a box or a circle?  Some images would definitely help to get this answered.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to this? I'm trying to do the same thing as you but I can't figure out how to do it exactly

Answer (score 2):

instead of shape layer with outline use solid layer with masks to recreate the outline. that seems to work for me..